# SciKit-learn--Gaussian Naive Bayes Implementantion

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have started using **Scikit-learn** and I am trying to train and predict a Gaussian Naive Bayes classificator. I don't know what I'm doing very well and I would like if someone could help me.

**PROBLEM**: I enter X quantity of items of type 1 and i have as response that they are of type 0

**HOW I DID IT:**
In order to generate the data for training I make this:

```
 #this is of type 1
    ganado={
            "Hora": "16:43:35",
            "Fecha": "19/06/2015",
            "Tiempo": 10,
            "Brazos": "der",
            "Sentado": "no",
            "Puntuacion Final Pasteles": 50,
            "Nombre": "usuario1",
            "Puntuacion Final Botellas": 33
        }
    #this is type 0
    perdido={
            "Hora": "16:43:35",
            "Fecha": "19/06/2015",
            "Tiempo": 10,
            "Brazos": "der",
            "Sentado": "no",
            "Puntuacion Final Pasteles": 4,
            "Nombre": "usuario1",
            "Puntuacion Final Botellas": 3
        }
    train=[]
    for repeticion in range(0,400):
        train.append(ganado)

    for repeticion in range(0,1):
            train.append(perdido)
```

I label the data by this weak condiction:

```
listLabel=[]
for data in train:
    condition=data["Puntuacion Final Pasteles"]+data["Puntuacion Final Botellas"]       
    if condition<20:
        listLabel.append(0)
    else:
        listLabel.append(1)
```

And I generate the data for testing like this:

```
  #this should be type 1
    pruebaGanado={
            "Hora": "16:43:35",
            "Fecha": "19/06/2015",
            "Tiempo": 10,
            "Brazos": "der",
            "Sentado": "no",
            "Puntuacion Final Pasteles": 10,
            "Nombre": "usuario1",
            "Puntuacion Final Botellas": 33
        }
    #this should be type 0
    pruebaPerdido={
            "Hora": "16:43:35",
            "Fecha": "19/06/2015",
            "Tiempo": 10,
            "Brazos": "der",
            "Sentado": "no",
            "Puntuacion Final Pasteles": 2,
            "Nombre": "usuario1",
            "Puntuacion Final Botellas": 3
        }
        test=[]
        for repeticion in range(0,420):
            test.append(pruebaGanado)
            test.append(pruebaPerdido)
```

After that, I use `train`and `listLabel` to train the classifier:

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
X=vec.fit_transform(train)
gnb = GaussianNB()
trained=gnb.fit(X.toarray(),listLabel)
```

Once I have trained the classifier I use the data for testing

```
testX=vec.fit_transform(test)
predicted=trained.predict(testX.toarray())
```

Finally the results are always `0`. Could you tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it please?

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you, So other can learn from it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Since your data has features that are not informative (same value for all data), I cleaned it a bit:

```
ganado={
    "a": 50,
    "b": 33
}
perdido={
        "a": 4,
        "b": 3
    }
pruebaGanado={
        "a": 10,
        "b": 33
    }
pruebaPerdido={
        "a": 2,
        "b": 3
    }
```

All the rest is not important, and cleaning your code will help you focus on what counts.

Now, Gaussian Naive Bayes is all about probability: as you may notice, the classifier tries to tell you that:

```
P((a,b)=(10,33)|class=0)*P(class=0)   >   P((a,b)=(10,33)|class=1)*P(class=1)
```

Because it assumes that both `a` and `b` have normal distribution, and the probabilities in this case are very low, the priors you gave it -(1,400) are negligible. You can see the Formula itself [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Parameter_estimation_and_event_models).
By the way, you can get the exact probabilities:

```
t = [pruebaGanado,pruebaPerdido]
t = vec.fit_transform(t)
print model.predict_proba(t.toarray())
#prints:
[[ 1.  0.]
[ 1.  0.]]
```

So the classifier is sure that 0 is the right class. Now, lets change a bit the test data:

```
pruebaGanado={
    "Puntuacion Final Pasteles": 20,
    "Puntuacion Final Botellas": 33
}
```

Now we have:

```
[[ 0.  1.]
[ 1.  0.]]
```

So you did nothing wrong, it is all a matter of calculation. By the way, I challenge you to replace `GaussianNB` with `MultinomialNB`, and see how the priors change it all.

Also, unless you have a very good reason to use here `GaussianNB`, I would consider using some kind of tree classification, as in my opinion it may suit your problem better.